# predictive text input(word suggestions) not working in AutoCompleteTextView in android application development

Tags: android, mobile

i have taken one `AutoCompleteTextView` in my `xml` like

```
      <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:ems="10" >
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

I want that, input in this `autocompletetextview` should work like `editText` in predictive mode.

when I take `editText` control in android, it automatically enables predictive text input(word suggestions).
To disable it, I have to use `TextNowordSuggestions` in `inputtype` property.

I know, we have to bound `autocompletetextview` to an adapter to get data, but right now that interface is not ready.

so is there some way, that adapter for now can be android default predictive text input or some other way.

which I can change later on in my next version of app.

Comment: @Hari, thanks for edit, i will keep these points in mind, next time i post my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried lot of things but finally i am taking `editText` as control to enable predictive text.
`autocompletetextview` can be used to load suggestion using an adapter like this

```
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_words);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this, R.layout.my_row, myWords);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i was looking to replace `myWords` in above code to get android dictionary suggestion.
but finally i have taken `editText`.

Answer (score 0):

After setting  text just do requsetfocus...it works fine for me..

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(
                this));

ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                search.setText(result.get(0));
                search.setSelection(search.getText().toString().length());
                search.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myAutoComplete);
    int inputType = myAutoComplete.getInputType();
    myAutoComplete.setRawInputType(inputType &= ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);
```